# Resetting textbox text via javascript

Tags: asp.net

```
function clickButton(e, buttonid)         
            var evt = e ? e : window.event;
            var bt = document.getElementById(buttonid);
            if (bt) {
                if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
                    bt.click();                                                  
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

txtChatMessage.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return clickButton(event,'" + btnSendChat.ClientID + "')");
```

this function is an attribute that is set in code behind file. How do I reset the text in textbox after the button click fires

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this, by passing  the text field from code behind `using this`, and `setting` its `value to empty string` in javascript

**In code behind**

```
txtChatMessage.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return clickButton(this, event,'" + btnSendChat.ClientID + "')");
```

**In javascript**

```
function clickButton(txt, e, buttonid){
   var evt = e ? e : window.event;
   var bt = document.getElementById(buttonid);
   if (bt) {
        if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
             bt.click();    
             txt.value = "";                                               
             return false;
   }
```

*The above code will over write the existing value of text box. To save it for later use we can use hidden field*

**In html**

```
<asp:hidden id="hdnText" runat="server" >
```

**In javascript**

```
function clickButton(txt, e, buttonid){
   var evt = e ? e : window.event;
   var bt = document.getElementById(buttonid);
   if (bt) {
        if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
             bt.click();    
             document.getElementById('<%= hdnText.ClientID %>').value = txt.value;                                               
             return false;
   }
```

**In Code behind**

Send text field to javascript function

```
txtChatMessage.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return clickButton(this, event,'" + btnSendChat.ClientID + "')");
```

Get value of textbox from hidden field

```
string textBoxValue = hdnText.Value;
```

Comment: I have tried setting the value via jquery but this does a funny behavior in mozilla firefox. Text Message doesnt go across the server but a blank message goes to the server

Comment: That is how it should do, you do not reset in javascript but do on server then.

Comment: I have update my answer for preserving value of text field using hidden field I  hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks budddy that helped me to ease things